# How to Get Paragraph List's all run elements as a List from OpenXml

Tags: c#, openxml

Hi I have List of OpenXmlElement `List<OpenXmlElement>` which is of Paragraphs of `OpenXMLElement` and I want to get all the runs from List of Paragraphs.

```
List<OpenXmlElement> oFieldNodes = GetParagraphs();
// this will return first paragraph's all runs.
List<Run> oRuns = oFieldNodes[0].Descendants<Run>().ToList<Run>();
```

How can I get List of Runs from all the Paragraphs from `oFieldNodes` using lambda expression or linq.

Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534336%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
List<Run> oRuns = oFieldNodes.SelectMany(o => o.Descendants<Run>()).ToList<Run>();
```

Comment: Glad to help @Anuj - if it solved your problem you could consider [marking it as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) (although you're under no obligation) :).

Comment: Thanks, I was searching for how to make a answer accepted.. :)